# Attribute.IsDefined equivalent in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, .net-core

I have a block of code that I tried convert to .NET Core

```
    public static bool IsAnonymousType(Type t)
    {
        return Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
            && t.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType
                && (t.Name.Contains("AnonymousType") || t.Name.Contains("AnonType"))
                    && (t.Name.StartsWith("<>", StringComparison.Ordinal) || t.Name.StartsWith("VB$", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                        && (t.GetTypeInfo().Attributes & AnonymousTypeAttributes) == AnonymousTypeAttributes;
    }
```

but I have problem with

```
  Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
```

Can anyone guide me about .NET Core equivalent ?

Comment: Support is [on the roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5381)

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate for me. it's on the roadmap for the main .net Core, right, but the answer provided in the linked question doesn't work for me. This question doesnt precise "DNX 5.0"